# focus border causing background-image to jump

Tags: html, css

Is there anyway to stop the background-image jumping when the input has focus.

A 2px border is added to the input when it gets focus but this causes the image to jump.

Adding `background-attachment: fixed` causes the image to disappear.

```css
.search_box {
  border: 1px solid #0065bd;
  background-color: #fff;
  background: url("http://png-5.findicons.com/files/icons/980/yuuminco/256/search.png");
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
  padding-right: 20px !important;
  padding-top: 2px !important;
  padding-bottom: 2px !important;
  padding-left: 5px !important;
    height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

.search_box:focus {
  background-color: #d9effc;
  border: 2px solid #0065bd;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="textbox search_box" name="keywords" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, define the background position for both dimension. I strongly recommend to do this in pixels. Then, on the focus-style, reset the background-position to -1px -1px to compensate the new extra border pixel.

```
.search_box {
  [...]
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.search_box:focus {
  [...]
  background-position: -1px -1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [box-shadow](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/).

I usually generate mine with this generator: [Box Shadow Generator](https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow)

```css
.search_box {
  border: 1px solid #0065bd;
  background-color: #fff;
  background: url("http://png-5.findicons.com/files/icons/980/yuuminco/256/search.png");
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
  padding-right: 20px !important;
  padding-top: 2px !important;
  padding-bottom: 2px !important;
  padding-left: 5px !important;
    height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}

.search_box:focus {
  background-color: #d9effc;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(0,101,189,1);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="textbox search_box" name="keywords" />
```

Comment: This is good, but the there are too many pixels of box-shadow.

Comment: @JamesDouglas you can make one with [this generator](https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `box-sizing: border-box;` on `.search_box` to make it stay the same size even with a bigger border, and `margin-left: -1px;`
 on `.search_box:focus` to keep it in the same place.

```css
.search_box {
  border: 1px solid #0065bd;
  background-color: #fff;
  background: url("http://png-5.findicons.com/files/icons/980/yuuminco/256/search.png");
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
  padding-right: 20px !important;
  padding-top: 2px !important;
  padding-bottom: 2px !important;
  padding-left: 5px !important;
    height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.search_box:focus {
  background-color: #d9effc;
  border: 2px solid #0065bd;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="textbox search_box" name="keywords" />
```